# Is it correct to say "Try your advice"?

Tags: usage

For example when I'm doing something my friend may give me some advice how I can do it better. Then can I say "Thank you. I'll *try your advice* next time."? Or I can say "I'll *follow your advice* next time."?

Comment: The second: "follow your advice". You can also say "try out your idea".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Try advice" doesn't sound quite correct. You '*follow*', or '*take*' advice, although doing so might involve 'trying' things suggested within it.

- I'll try your suggestion
- I'll follow your advice
- I'll try the things you suggested
- I'll try the things as you advised